# Html lang change

Tags: php, html, lang

```
$this->output('<a href="'.qa_path_html('categories').'" class="king-cat-link">'.qa_lang_html('main/nav_categories').'</a>');
```

I've got this line, where:

```
qa_lang_html('main/nav_categories')
```

is the name of category- **Categories**

How can i change it?

Comment: What platform of PHP is it?

Comment: PHP version 5.4.30   I have King Media from codecanyon canyon.net/item/king-media/7877877